# JQuery Show local div on multiple div rows

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically displaying multiple rows of div's.

Div sets look like this:

```
<div class="triggerbutton">
    <img src="/images/clickme.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="hiddendivs" style="display:none;">
    some stuff here 
</div>
```

I am using this JQuery:

```
$('.triggerbutton').click(function() {

    $('.hiddendivs').show('slow');

});
```

But I only want the hiddendivs after the triggerbutton to be showed and not all the hiddendivs available.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `hiddendivs` is the next sibling you could use

```
$('.triggerbutton').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show('slow');
});
```

Comment: @PatsyIssa: not necessary on this case

Comment: might as well make it generic :)

Comment: @Patsy Issa: `next` with selector doesn't get the next element matching but the next element ONLY if matches the selector ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.triggerbutton').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.hiddendivs').show('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.next()` in jQuery

```
$('.triggerbutton').click(function() {

    $(this).next().show('slow');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with code. It works like this, find next immediate div with class hiddendivs and shows it.

```
$('.triggerbutton').click(function() {

    $(this).next('div.hiddendivs').show('slow');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `next` you will only refer to the next element following the selector. You can also use `nextAll` for all following divs:

```
$('.triggerbutton').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.hiddendivs').show('slow');
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bWKj2/)